# Does CSS3 box-sizing work in Facebook app: padding or sizing issue, creating unwanted scrollbars?

Tags: facebook, css, facebook-graph-api, padding

Our Facebook app displays unwanted scrollbars, even though we defined the width as 500px. This app appears within the context of Facebook fan pages.

We originally set the width at 520px with side padding of 10px on the left and right. We used the CSS3 box-sizing property (and its browser variants) and set it to border-box.

Then we weren't sure if Facebook somehow stripped out the box-sizing property, so we set the width to 500px. Still the scrollbars won't go away.

Here's an example: http://www.facebook.com/coboak?sk=app_198939416792674

1) How to eliminate the scrollbars? (Yes, the app is configured with Auto-Resize.)

2) Does Facebook support the box-sizing property (and its browser variants)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) remove `width: 520px;` from `#main_box`

2) `box-sizing` will affect only browsers which support it, no matter if it's on facebook

Comment: Thanks, MatTheCat. This is what we thought, too, re box-sizing. If we set #main_box to to use "box-sizing: border-box," shouldn't this work (which is what we did at one point)?

Comment: I don't understand, #main_box has no margin or padding so box-sizing won't change anything. It's just larger than #page_box.